# What is the difference between "悪化した場合" and "悪化する場合"?

Tags: grammar

> 「危機対応融資」は、災害や金融危機などで一時的に業績が悪化した場合に、融資を受けられる制度です。

I don't think it make sense if "悪化した場合" is interpreted as past tense in this sentence.

Will the original meaning be altered somehow if it is updated into "悪化する場合"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,悪化した does make sense in the past tense and should maintain so. In fact it is the non-past tense (i.e.悪化する) that doesnt make sense.

To put it simply, 悪化した  and not 悪化する because bussiness perfmance has been worsened (悪化した), not will be worsened(悪化する).

It only make sense to provide 危機対応融資 to bussiness whose performance has been worsened by natural disaster or financial crisis. Therefore, 悪化 is a thing in the past and should be in past tense